# Find instances associated with multiple (all) instances from other model in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, database, join, sequelize.js

Simplified Sequelize model example:

```
Post.belongsToMany(Tag)
Tag.belongsToMany(Post)
```

How do I `findAll` Posts that is associated with ALL of a set of tags?

Example dataset:

```
post
{ id: 1 }
{ id: 2 }

tag
{ id: 10 }
{ id: 11 }

post_tag
{ post_id: 1, tag_id: 10 }
{ post_id: 2, tag_id: 10 }
{ post_id: 2, tag_id: 11 }
```

So if the tags in question is **10** and **11**, the query should return **Post 2** since it is associated with both tags, but not **Post 1** since it is not associated with all the tags. (the number of tags could of course be more than two)

Comment: did the answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to construct this request in one Sequelize `findAll` request, but I had to drop down to raw SQL to accomplish your task. Here are two approaches:

#### 1. Get the post IDs and query `Post.findAll` with the results

Find `post_ids` that contain all tags

```
const postIds = await db.query(`
  SELECT post_id FROM (
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS counter
    FROM post_tag
    GROUP BY post_id
  ) AS tbl
  WHERE counter = (SELECT count(*) as COUNT from tags);;
`, {type: db.QueryTypes.SELECT})
```

Find posts that are present in the `postIds` array

```
const posts = await Post.findAll({
  where: {
    id: {
      $in: postIds.map(x => x.post_id)
    }
  }
});
```

#### 2. Get posts in one SQL statement

```
const posts = await db.query(`
  SELECT *
  FROM posts
  WHERE id IN (
    SELECT post_id FROM (
      SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS counter
      FROM post_tag
      GROUP BY post_id
    ) AS tbl
    WHERE counter = (SELECT count(*) as COUNT from tags)
  )
`, {type: db.QueryTypes.SELECT});
```

(fwiw, I added both approaches because I prefer less raw SQL in application code)